# Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined at u/newrelic<privetstring>

Tags: docker, webpack, react-typescript, linux-mint, react-fullstack

My OS is Linux-mint and I have a React typescript app. working with yarn (not npm) and docker containers for APISIX and front-end. Also, I have Webpack but without out Webpack configuration file.

I researched solutions on the web and did not find something that worked for me.
I also restarted the computer, removed and restarted for docker, and removed and cloned the repository again.

Can you give me solutions with instructions and examples of what to do? :)

After executing 'yarn dev', the server is up, and I get the localhost port. when I open the localhost URL on Chrom the UI is **white**, and I do not see the app.

In the console getting the **error** ''Uncaught ReferenceError: **webpack_require** is not defined
at u/newrelic"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing it from-

```
 "@newrelic/browser-agent": "^1.240.0"
```

to-

```
"@newrelic/browser-agent": "1.240.0"
```

without the ^